# Background image not sizing correctly?

Tags: html, css, image

So on my phone, this site looks like this:

[image: img]

However, on my PC with a similar size viewport, it looks like this:

[image: img]

Notice the background image difference.

I can't really understand why this is happening or how to fix it, but what I can do is ask on here and provide the CSS for the background image.

**CSS:**

```css
.fw-bg--1 {
  width: auto !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/898930011359297629/925860960038694922/terrie-shum-edotown2.png);
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information to help me, just let me know!

Comment: which of them is the desired result?

Comment: also, put spaces before your `!important`s to make sure the styles are properly parsed.

Comment: @EliranMalka I want it to look like how it does on my desktop. (Zoomed out)

Comment: i see, please provide some more context; what is the phone's model? what screen size does it have? operating system? etc. etc.

Comment: Can you provide the code for all relevant elements (HTML & CSS) please? It's hard to tell just by having the background style.

Comment: @Leo I hope you don't mind, it's in VueJS and I'm also using Bootstrap 5 for it. https://pastebin.com/iwVtfY0V <--- there is the Header component

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem, but I'm quite sure it is the `cover`. I think the element's `height` or `width` (or both) is getting too big, so the `background-size: cover` expands the image until it touches the farthest edge.

Comment: @Leo have you tried on a phone viewing the site? It's not reproducible by a similar-sized window as a phone... I don't know why which means it's hard to figure out the issue.,

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/leodeslf/87bqo4ry/5/), as you can see, it's fine, even without the `!important` rules. So I think Bootstrap is doing something else under the hood (may be based on the pixel density) on another element, element which I don't have access to. I cannot give further information as I don't use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a background-image is placed at the top-left corner of an element, and repeated both vertically and horizontally, try defining a background-position center to fix this, your code would be something like this :

```
.fw-bg--1 {
  width: auto!important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-position:center
  background-attachment: fixed!important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,.8),rgba(0,0,0,.8) 40%,rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/898930011359297629/925860960038694922/terrie-shum-edotown2.png);
}
```

Comment: it's just really zoomed in though. How would I fix this? It's probably due to the height being 100vh right? Is there another way I can make the header image take up a similar amount of space